# Laravel translate

Tags: php, laravel

In my blade file, as the declension of words, I use the following construction:

```
echo Lang::choice('apple|apples|', $count, [], 'ru');
```

Now I need to do a translation in my Controller, I'm trying to do this:

```
$realTime = Carbon::now();
$diff = $realTime->diffInDays($item->created_at);
$date = 7 - $diff;
'message' => 'To left: '.$date.' '.<?php echo Lang::choice('day|days|', $date, [], 'ru'); ?>.'',
```

But it's not work, how I can use this translation method in the controller correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this,
laravel localization give you some options to use globally in your app,

in your case you can do this:

```
$realTime = Carbon::now();
$diff = $realTime->diffInDays($item->created_at);
$date = 7 - $diff;
'message' => 'To left: '.$date. ' ' . trans_choice('day|days|', $date, [], 'ru'),
```

please check documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/localization#pluralization

i hope can help you

Comment: it's not work, i received `(T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` error :( and I forgot to say for clarification, I use Laravel 5.1